# For critical sections - when to use std::mutex vs std::atomic_flag?

Tags: c++, stl

Here is an implementation of Spinlock class using STL atomic_flag, Taken from https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/the-atomic-flag.

```
class Spinlock{
public:
  Spinlock(): flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {}

  void lock(){
    while( flag.test_and_set() );
  }

  void unlock(){
    flag.clear();
  }

 private:
   std::atomic_flag flag;
 };
```

And I can use it for any critical section of the code:

```
 void myfunction() {
     std::lock_guard<Spinlock> guard(_spinLock);
     ...
 }
```

Revised question:

For critical sections, seems I now have two choices - std::mutex and std::atomic_flag. When does it make sense to use one over the other?

Comment: "and that it is more efficient" [citation needed]. That's a pretty broad statement. A spinlock isn't the best implementation of a mutex in every case

Comment: Here is a citation: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/the-atomic-flag.

Comment: The spinlock vs mutex part in that article is a very nice demo that a spinlock _is not_ always efficient. The program used does nothing (literally just sleeps) yet uses up a full CPU core in the spinlock example.

Comment: Spinlocks in general should be avoided. At best they're giving you a marginal improvement on latencies, in the worst case they may cause a priority inversion, due to throwing off the schedulers heuristics. A couple of months ago Linus Torvalds had to rekt one of the developers of Stadia on their poor benchmarking of various locking mechanisms and how their conclusions were "pure garbage" (sic) https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=189711&curpostid=189723

Answer (score 4):

`std::mutex` can be used also in conjunction with [conditions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), which your class cannot directly do. It also works nicely with scoped locks.

Asides from that, your statement

> it is more efficient

is not categorically true. The line

```
while( flag.test_and_set() );
```

is [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), which in some settings is efficient, and in other settings inferior to exponential backoff, for example.

Comment: My remark about efficiency is based on the citation that I have now added to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter I'm unsure how you see there that it is more efficient. What it states is that a spinlock exhibits the behaviour you'd expect from it (tying up a core), whereas the mutex doesn't do that. Tying up a core, in itself, is not an indication of efficiency. Getting more workload done is.

Answer (score 4):

The question is: what do you want to achieve and what sacrifices are you willing to make for that?

**std::atomic_flag** is constantly asking for the lock to get access to the critical section, which keeps the CPU core on which it is running 100% busy. It won't be a problem if you have enough cores you can operate with, or not many of your threads are operating on the same critical section at the same time. It saves an expensive context switch though between user space and kernel space.

**std::mutex** on the other hand will not keep its core busy. You can't observe a significant load on any of the cores with this solution. That's because the thread gets suspended by the scheduler while other threads do some work. It means that the state of the thread gets stored and then restored and resumed later.